# How to fix Apache Camel WARN about depracated syntax

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

```
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("timer?period=12000&repeatCount=1")
                .log("started")
                .streamCaching()
                .to("sql:select * from TABLE WHERE ROWNUM < 100" +
                        "?dataSource=#dataSource")
                .split()
                .body()
                    .process(new convertToJSON())
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/html"))
                    .to(url)
                .end()
                .log("Sent");
    }
```

I have this camel route which works fine but I get WARN in console:

```
2019-05-30 16:02:51.856  WARN 11284 --- [- timer://timer] o.a.c.language.simple.SimpleLanguage     : Simple language is using deprecated syntax: body. You should migrate to use newer syntax that uses ${xxx} style.
```

How to fix this WARN ??

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to access the exchange body, you should use "${body}" in your simple expression.

For example:

```
.log("${body}")
```

The above will log the body of the exchange.

Comment: In addition, you do not need .body() at all. Your processor and the following code will be executed on the exchange body by default.